# Is [language-lawyer] really an effective characterization, or a borderline meta-tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

[language-lawyer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-lawyer)

> For questions about the intricacies of formal or authoritative
> specifications of programming languages and environments. Typical
> questions concern gaps between "what will usually work in practice"
> and "what the spec actually guarantees", but problems with
> understanding the structure of the spec are also on topic.

This tag just rubs me the wrong way.  Is it really an effective characterization, or a borderline [meta-tag?](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/)

Comment: Looks like a junk tag to me: http://catb.org/jargon/html/L/language-lawyer.html

Comment: Why on Earth would 21 people follow that tag?

Comment: @BilltheLizard: The vast majority of questions tagged [language-lawyer] are also tagged [c] or [c++].

Comment: It's mostly a C++ tag that's used to separate out questions that are about pedantic details rather than problems that happen to be written in C++. And as such, I regularly add the tag to such questions.

Comment: I would vote for burninating. It seems like obscure jargon, and it isn't all that self-explanatory. If someone has a question about a programming language, I think they should just tag it with the language's tag.

Comment: @smcg: It appears that the C++ folks are using it as a "folder" to separate the genuine C++ programming questions from the ones having to do with obscure language semantics.

Comment: So, it's like [c++-faq] but without the c++- (lol "c plus plus minus") prefix?

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn: More like [c++-obscure-specifications-faq]

Comment: How about merging it with [tag:language-specifications]?

Comment: I find it amusing that those complaining about the metataggery, esotericism and pedantic nature of [tag:language-lawyer] questions have gone to such lengths to pick apart its true meaning. Irony, much? :)

Comment: Since we're being language-lawyers.. no, there's no irony.  There's a poetic coincidence, but definitely no irony ;)

Answer (score 69, accepted):

The [language-lawyer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-lawyer) tag is a(nother) ***C++ peculiarity*** which users of other languages will most likely not understand, but which is quite important and known in the C++ community.

***C++*** isn't so much designed and specified (which is one of the reasons why "language-specifications" doesn't cut it), as it ***is grown*** — or, rather: ***exuberantly mushroomed***. Remember, we're talking the language which enabled one of its most notorious features, *template meta-programming*, [by accident](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/10?m=1706594#1706594). The latest edition of the C++ standard has ~1.3k pages (the one before that, BTW, had "only" 700 pages), plus it includes the C standard by reference.
That makes for a lot of room for language lawyers, which made this term a ***rather well-known*** one. I probably first encountered the term in `comp.lang.c++.moderated` about ***10-15 years ago***.

In C++, a language-lawyering question would be one that discusses some peculiarity of C++ which 80% of the users of the language either (hopefully) never run into, or, *if they happen to run into it*, then they don't realize that they've run into even if they had read that question just yesterday, or, *if they realize it*, they would ask a question that ought to be answered by "just don't do this".

Language-lawyering mostly involves pedantic wankery and throwing standard references at each other, but, occasionally, something useful comes out of it.<sup>1</sup>

On Stackoverflow.com, if you have a C++ question that asks for a language lawyer, you usually hope [Johannes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34509/) sees it. If SO failed me on such a question, I'd ask on `comp.lang.c++.moderated`, where all the luminaries read and, sometimes, post.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Erwin Unruh told me once he always meant to prove templates are a Turing-complete compile-time language. He never got around doing so before it was proven by (his own!) example through the emerging template meta-programming. But had he proved it, this would have been useful language-lawyering.</sub>

Comment: I think this explanation makes the strongest case for keeping the tag.  It is definitely a useful categorization for those with this very specialized interest, and would conceivably be followed, filtered upon, and Google searched.  +1 from me.

Comment: why isn't this tag called _c++-language-lawyer_?

Comment: @gnat: Since it's possible to search for [C++] [language-lawyer], I don't think we need to make it more specific.

Comment: @gnat: Because the term "language lawyer" is not at all specific to C++. It can very easily apply to C, and it could easily apply to any language. See my answer.

Comment: @KeithThompson the largest size C specification I could find - ANSI C standard (C99) [ISO/IEC 9899:TC2](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf) - is less than 600 pages pdf - this doesn't look impressive compared to "~1.3k pages" mentioned by sbi for C++ standard. In fact, it's about same size as [Java 7 edition JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/jls7.pdf) which is about 600 pages as well. Are C (ANSI?) or Java really as complicated as C++?

Comment: @gnat: The latest [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) is closer to 700 pages (the link is to the public draft). No, C isn't as complicated as C++; I never said it was. But it's certainly complicated enough to support language-lawyering. My point is simply that "language lawyer" is in no way a C++-specific term.

Comment: @gnat: `why isn't this tag called c++-language-lawyer?` because that breaks normalisation ;)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit well... what about something like `cpp-la-la` then? :)

Comment: @KeithThompson: The n3797 version of C++14 I mostly use is 1366 pages. However there is something like 800 pages under 'library'.

Comment: The only knowledgeable answer here.

Comment: There are probably questions in [tag:common-lisp] that could benefit from  [tag:language-lawyer].  It's another language that grew over a long period of time, has lots of places where even if 90% of implementations do it one way, the spec still leaves it open, etc.

Comment: I agree with @KeithThompson that this isn't *really* C++ specific (despite our disagreement about just *how* generally applicable it is), but I suspect C++ is the *most* language-lawyer-able language there is. (This is almost certainly true if you restrict the field to mainstream languages.)

Answer (score 37):

The term "language lawyer" is not at all specific to C++. The C++ standard is sufficiently large and complex that it's a rich source of language-lawyerly questions, but the term can easily apply to just about *any* language, especially one defined by an official standard document. (For example, I consider myself a C language lawyer; I used to be an Ada language lawyer as well.)

I'd say that any question that's about the exact meaning of the wording in a language standard, without necessarily involving practical programming questions, is an appropriate [language-lawyer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-lawyer) question.

A hypothetical example: A question about the exact meaning of "lvalue" in C would be a good language-lawyer question. Practically speaking, the meaning is reasonably clear (it's an expression that designates an object, derived from the fact that it can appear on the *left* side of an assignment), but the three released versions of the ISO standard have three differently worded definitions of the term.

Tagging a question [language-lawyer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-lawyer) has two benefits: it brings it to the attention of strange people like me who actually like questions like that (I have it in my list of favorate tags), and it warns away those who are more interested in practical programming questions.

I say keep it.

Comment: I understand that downvotes on meta merely express disagreement, but I'm still a bit bewildered. What's the harm of keeping the language-lawyer tag? It's meaningful, and there are some of us who actually follow it.

Comment: This term was even used in the **official** Python documentation as late as [version 2.5](https://docs.python.org/release/2.5/) to describe the "Language Reference" section. So this term is quite familiar to erudite Pythonistas. I say keep it as well.

Comment: Yes, yes, this applies to *any* language! For instance, it applies to *Ada*! (/end sarcasm) I agree that it applies to certain languages that aren't C++, but lots of languages don't even actually have official standards.

Comment: @KyleStrand: I don't understand the sarcasm. Lots of languages do have standards, and plenty of languages that don't have formal standards are still susceptible to language-lawyering.  Can you make your point without the sarcasm? (I'm honestly not sure what your point is).

Comment: @KeithThompson My point is that Ada is an excellent example of a language that, like C++, has a very complex standard; so it's therefore a very bad example of a language demonstrating that "any" language is susceptible to language-lawyering. For instance, is `bash` a good language-lawyer candidate? What about Perl v. 1?

Comment: @KyleStrand: Point taken; I've weaseled the wording a bit. Perl v.1? Maybe not. Bash? Its manual is about half a megabyte, mostly plain text, so why not?

Comment: @KeithThompson It's got complexities and oddities, sure, but a manual is not a standard; how much nitpicky pedantics can you really get into with Bash? Your script either works, or it's buggy, or there's a bug in Bash (in which case your script is still buggy, in a sense). And maybe this isn't even a distinction of how big or complex the documentation for the language is; I'd be more open to the idea that the *subset* of Bash that attempts to conform to the POSIX standard for command-shells is open to language-lawyering--but they're you're really language-lawyering POSIX, not Bash.

Comment: @KyleStrand: Since we're in agreement that "language-lawyer" can reasonably apply to a number of different languages, I don't think it's worthwhile, shall we say, language-lawyering the exact set of languages it applies to.

Comment: @KeithThompson I was curious about this, so I made [a query that checks what tags are used alongside \[language-lawyer\] on StackOverflow.](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1085953/c-needs-a-legal-team) Language Lawyering seems to be an overwhelmingly C(++) phenomenon, at least if StackOverflow post count is anything to go by. Out of 4,723 LL posts, 3,637 of them are C++, 892 are C. Compare to: Java: 76, C#: 41, Python: 33, Ruby: 3, JS: 39, Rust: 12, (g)Fortran: 5, Perl: 4, Bash: 3, Shell: 3, Haskell: 2, VB: 2, PHP: 2, Swift: 1, Powershell: 1, ObjC: 0, Erlang: 0

Answer (score 15):

I think it's worth keeping. It separates out actual questions that, for example, contain actual C++ code, from those which are purely about one interpretation or another of an obscure clause in the Standard.

Comment: What about [language-features] or [language-design]? Seems like this is already adequately covered by other tags.

Comment: Also a multitude of others in [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-\*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-*)

Comment: [language-design] would surely imply a question about *why* the spec says what it does, rather than *what* it says and how to interpret it, at the very least.

Answer (score -11):

Merge with [language-specifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-specifications)

Comment: Vote to agree or disagree.

Comment: [language-specifications] is great because 1) it's a much more widely-recognized term 2) it's applicable to other languages and not just C++ 3) people will actually search for it... I know I'll add that to my favorite tags if we can somehow clean it up and make it a proper tag (whatever that means). Although it should be mentioned that its very meaning also means it probably can't stand on its own without an accompanying language tag. So, I dunno...

Comment: Let this sit for at least a couple days before taking any action. That'll give all the C++ regulars a chance to see this.

Comment: I think destroying the tag would be a poor idea. "language lawyer" carries a connotation substantially different from "language specifications", so merging the two would result in substantial information loss. In theory the difference probably should be trivial, but in fact it's fairly substantial.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: I guess the fact that it carries an *"I are pedantic"* connotation is what bothers me about it. I don't see how that is relevant to the tagging/categorization process.

Comment: It makes quite a bit of difference in both the type of answer expected and the group of people likely to be interested in answering the question. On a meta-meta level (so to speak) I think the push to remove this (among other things) is basically an attempt at serving the people who almost never use the site, at the expense of those who do so regularly. Google is important, but frequent users are too.

Comment: Can't see this answer..., but seems to be the most important.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: I'd feel better about this tag if the Tag Wiki had some relevant content in it... A FAQ list, perhaps?

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn: How is "language-lawyer" not applicable to languages other than C++? See [my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/142223/167210) for further discussion.

Comment: @KeithThompson: The tag is not language-specific, although it's used mostly by the C++ and C crowd, in no small part because they have this thing called Undefined Behavior.  Also, we're talking about something that happened a year ago?

Comment: -17 and the most specific argument to having both is essentially "they're different"...

Comment: @Dukeling: Check out the checkmark.

Comment: Well, the intertwined question would be whether having a language-specifications tag is even useful - are there questions that aren't quite on the language-lawyer level, but are still about specifically about language-specifications **in the same language** (the main argument in the accepted answer, as I read it, is that C++ is special)? And, @ 42 open questions (**five** of those tagged C++) for language-specifications, it really won't add a lot to the noise to have those questions and language-lawyer's classify as one and the same. Well, those are my thoughts at least.

Answer (score -12):

Burninate.  Seems like a meta tag, and I can't seriously believe that *anyone* will ever google, "Language-Lawyer".

I wrote this post two years ago; and it seems to be as true today as it was two years ago.  Here's a present day screen shot of the first 'fold' for Language lawyer:

[image]

As you can see, the first two links are simply duplicates of one another; the third link is another definition, the fourth is a Stack Overflow tag (not particularly helpful, unless you're actually looking for a language-lawyer question -- and even then, you get to scroll through a few pages to find what you're looking for), and the fifth is about sign language.

Notice that all the sponsored ads are about finding a lawyer.  I didn't include results 6-10 because they are even less relevant than results 1-5 (if such a thing were possible).

This is the very definition of a meta tag -- it's a tag that can't tell you about the problem on its own. A commenter brought up 'civilians' and '`UItableViewCell`'.

Here are the first five google results for `UItableViewCell`:

[image: UItableViewCell]

As you can see, all of the search results hone in exactly on a language, a problem, and even a video(!).  While I wouldn't suggest having `UItableViewCell` be the only tag on a question; it would get us much farther than having `language-lawyer` be the only tag on a question.

People like it, I get that. But it *is* a meta tag.

There's also the argument that

> People are following the tag deliberately, using it as a marker of questions that are interesting to them. That's an exceptionally good indication of utility.

People also used to [ask others to "ignore the fun tag"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3283/what-kind-of-place-should-there-be-for-contest-questions), so they could keep the fun tag around.  The problem is; while these questions may be 'fun' they're not really in the scope of Stack Overflow.

Likewise; the Language-Lawyer tag serves the interest of a very small group of people who:

1. Enjoy arguing language semantics.
2. Like to post teaser questions just to argue language semantics.
3. Have these questions show up in the moderator queue due to flags.

3 alone is a good reason to remove the tag; and #1 and #2 also are outside the scope of Stack Overflow.  Not to mention, these questions usually fall this very basic tenet of our site:

> Focus on questions about an actual problem you have faced. Include details about what you have tried and exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: I think you hit the important part there. "Would someone search for this when seeking questions/answers?" should be one of the top criteria for a legitimate tag.

Comment: Another rule of thumb that's come up in previous discussions is "would it make sense for this to be the only tag on a question?"

Comment: I can not only imagine somebody using it, but can say with certainty that it *has* been used.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker: Yes, I meant used to find questions/answers here via Google.

Comment: I googled it...

Comment: I think [sbi makes a good case here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142058/is-language-lawyer-really-an-effective-characterization-or-a-borderline-meta/142180#142180).  It's certainly not harmful to keep it around, and seems quite helpful to the subset of people that are interested in it.

Comment: People are following the tag deliberately, using it as a marker of questions that are interesting to them. That's an _exceptionally_ good indication of utility.

Comment: @DonalFellows: I follow the tag deliberately. I find it an __exceptionally__ good indication of authority.

Comment: "If the outside audience has to guess what your terminology means, it's not good terminology"  That's totally bizarre.  All of the iOS tags, say ("UItableViewCell!") would be completely meaningless to civilians.  SO is for experts to discuss arcane details with other experts. Civilians are irrelevant.