# Is the language-lawyer tag appropriate if I'm not quoting a standard?

Tags: discussion, tags

I occasionally use the [language-lawyer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-lawyer) tag for questions that are abstract but not asking about a specific part of a language standard. Here's a recent example.

[Unordered function evaluation for functions returning void](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27263729/unordered-function-evaluation-for-functions-returning-void)

This question received a couple downvotes and I understand that. (It's doing better now that there's an answer.) It's not quite what people expect - there's no practical application behind the question - so I want a tag that warns people about that.

On the other hand, [language-lawyer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-lawyer) sounds like I should be citing clauses or arguing semantics of the text of the standard so maybe I'm just creating clutter for people who are looking for that sort of thing.

What do folks expect when they see [language-lawyer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-lawyer)? Is it a good tag for abstract questions that are not about a specific practical problem but which are also not asking about a specific portion of a language standard? If not, is there a better tag for this?

This meta SO answer comes close.

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256514/1128289

After reading it I'm still unsure. In the linked question, I'm not throwing references around but it does fulfill the pedantic wankery criterion.

Comment: The question also received 6 upvotes and a very solid answer.

Comment: Things seemed rockier at first and I've seen this pattern before where the downvotes stop when a solid answer shows up. Either way, I'm not terribly worried. I just want to know if there's a better "abstract but not standard quoting" tag.

Comment: People may quote the standard on questions that aren't tagged language-lawyer, but they usually don't have to.

Comment: If you are expecting the answers to not only be practical but also backed up by references from the standard saying that they are legal C or C++ code then I think the tag is appropriate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be honest, I'd say the downvotes are probably explained by talking about C/C++ in combination with the language-lawyer tag. If you are insisting on being formal, be formal yourself.

The language-lawyer tag basically says that you are asking for answers backed by the relevant Standard, even if your question itself does not quote directly from the standard. However, your question still should use consistent and appropriate wording. Take for example C++, we'd expect you to know the difference between declarations and definitions. Formal answers will quote just the relevant parts of the standard. They're not going to rehash basic concepts.

Comment: Could you explain what's wrong with using "C/C++"? Is that really a bad phrasing to use for features that are identical in the languages?

Comment: @Praxeolitic: The languages effectively forked around 1996 or so, with the C++98 and C99 standards formalizing the split. Even if certain constructs compile in both languages, the language-lawyer reasons why they do are generally different. In particular, the C++ core language specification is pretty much a full rewrite (the library part is an extension, though)

Comment: A full rewrite? I had no idea! Why is that? I know that's a big question. Is there somewhere to get more info about this?

Comment: Quite a few places. C++ actually has something of an official history book, "The Design & Evolution of C++".