# [spec], [specification], [specifications]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

We have these three tags, that seem to be about the same thing:

- [spec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spec) (× 231)
- [specification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/specification) (× 175)
- [specifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/specifications) (× 432)

I think we should use only *one* tag -- if we need it at all, that is.

Comment: I'm torn between "this is way too broad, language specification questions don't need to be tagged" (because for the most part, that's what they are) and "...but maybe they do, because that's what tags are for".

Comment: @KevinBrown Questions about C++ language specs get [language-lawyer].  There's a [jls] tag for Java spec questions.  I agree, having a general language spec tag isn't providing any additional value over the language-specific spec tags.

Answer (score 20):

The tags don't need to be burninated, they do serve a purpose. But they should be combined through synonyms.

---

[spec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spec) should **definitely be a synonym of [specification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/specification)**, the tag wiki even mentions it.

> Spec is a simpler version of "specification", that is a description of the resources offered by a technology, like a programming language. https://stackoverflow.com/tags/specification/info

And then we have [specifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/specifications) and [specification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/specification), which are for the same thing.

Tag wiki of [specifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/specifications)

> A specification (often abbreviated as spec) is an explicit set of requirements to be satisfied by a material, product, or service.[wikipedia]

Tag wiki of [specification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/specification)

> An specification, also comonly refered as spec is a description of a defined tecnology and the resources it offers.

*Both of which appear to have been [ripped from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specification_(technical_standard)) at the time of creation.*

**My vote goes to [specification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/specification) being the central tag.**

---

Of course, while we are sitting here waiting for the synonym, *look through some of the questions*. This is the best time to clean up questions that shouldn't be open, or questions with the wrong tags, and in general improve Stack Overflow.

There are [37 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rspec+specifications+OR+rspec+spec+OR+rspec+specification) that use any of the tags in combination with [rspec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rspec). Considering [rspec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rspec) is for testing and it all revolves around a "specification", the extra tag probably doesn't need to be there.

There are also [74 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/specifications+java+OR+spec+java+OR+specification+java+OR+language-specifications+java) tagged in combination with [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) which should be re-tagged with the Java Language Specification tag [jls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jls) instead.

There are [33 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/specifications%20c%2b%2b%20or%20spec%20c%2b%2b%20or%20specification%20c%2b%2b%20or%20language-specifications%20c%2b%2b) that use it in combination with [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) that should be re-tagged with [language-lawyer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-lawyer), the tag that [is basically all about the c++ spec](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256510/359284).

Comment: You fleshed out the case for synonymization or merging, well done. But for the love of all, don't try manual re-tagging a minimum of 400 questions for something to do. Let's just get a synonym, and then (or instead) let a mod simply merge them all in one go. There are lots of other such request where attention to each individual question might not be completely wasted.

Comment: @Deduplicator My bad, originally I wrote it as a burnination request and then later switched it to a synonym request. I've corrected that paragraph.