# What is the difference between the [c++], [c++11] and [c++14] tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

I posted *[What is the standard compliant way to convert a signed integral value to a sortable, unsigned in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33569303/what-is-the-standard-compliant-way-to-convert-a-signed-integral-value-to-a-sorta)*

And the [c++11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) [c++14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) tags were removed in an edit, but I reverted because I wanted a standards-related answer related to undefined behaviour (that tag was also removed).

I would like this question to be correctly tagged, so I'm coming here. Thoughts?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265844/should-i-not-use-the-generic-tag-if-my-solution-is-limited-to-a-specific-version (I don't see your question as version-specific.)

Comment: "I don't understand why this occurred, and I'd like to do things correctly whenever possible, so I came here for help" seems like a pretty reasonable question to me. I wonder why you got a downvote?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The tag to use when you specifically want to get an answer based on strictly the C++ standard (any version) rather than current implementations is [language-lawyer].

The [c++11] and [c++14] tags make sense if and only if you want an answer that specifically covers these and only these versions of the standard. Without those tags, answerers should already take into account the fact that the current C++ standard is C++14, but may also cover C++11, C++03 and C++98 in their answers.

It makes sense to me to remove the language version tags.

As for the [undefined-behavior] tag, that doesn't seem to me to apply to your question. I would think that that is more relevant for questions that cover a specific result of undefined behaviour, whereas your question is about getting a valid C++ answer, which already implies no undefined behaviour without the need for a tag.

Comment: edited as per your suggestions, thank you

Comment: Why does [tag:language-lawyer] exist?  Isn't that a meta-tag?

Comment: @Joe See [Is language-lawyer really an effective characterization, or a borderline meta-tag?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256510/is-language-lawyer-really-an-effective-characterization-or-a-borderline-meta)

Comment: @Joe: Yes, but an exceptionally valuable one.

Comment: "...questions that cover a specific result of undefined behaviour..." Have you actually ever had any luck asking questions of this sort? I find the C++ community here wildly opposed to the idea of even considering what actually happens when a program triggers undefined behavior.

Comment: @KyleStrand I don't remember seeing such questions at all recently and haven't ever asked them myself in the past, but I have no problem with such questions and if I see one that's well-asked, interesting and unanswered, I will try to answer it.

Comment: @hvd That's very good to know! I don't know if you'll think it meets your criteria (there is an answer, though I'm not sure it's correct), but one such question I've asked is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32132058/1858225). (Note that the first several comments primarily consist of objections to my attempt to figure this out.)

Comment: @KyleStrand I think it'll be hard to get an answer for it, sorry. If clang and GCC don't act on the UB, then no one will be able to answer that authoritatively without a deep analysis of the compilers' source code, or documentation somewhere that the compilers officially support this as an extension. I don't expect such documentation to exist, and analysing even one C++ compiler is probably too much to expect from an answerer, let alone six separate versions. If clang or GCC does act on the UB, a short example could make for an interesting answer, but I have no such example.

Comment: Well, thanks for taking a look :)

Comment: @KyleStrand it is very hard to ask those kinds of questions well, one of the few times I was able to [provide a solid explanation for UB](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32507135/1708801) was because it was well documented already by John Regehr who does a lot of research in this area. Another similar case such as Linux null pointer check removal is also well documented. Otherwise you would have to know what exactly the compiler is doing. It is a fascinating subject but hard to get good answers to.

Comment: @KyleStrand also as hvd says, how [gcc and clang exploit UB can vary greatly over versions](http://blog.regehr.org/archives/1234).

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour That link seems to indicate that Clang doesn't *ever* treat UB differently from version to version. Every column in the Clang table is identical.

Comment: Though of course he's testing a very small subset of UBs, and it's not clear whether the *way* in which Clang "takes advantage of" each instance remains consistent from version to version.

Comment: @Joe By the "Can someone be an expert in that topic?" test, [tag:language-lawyer] is appropriate for an expert in the topic of fine points of standard interpretation.

Comment: @KyleStrand yes, that is likely to do w/ clang being much younger also the fact that [Chris Lattner says that UB are land mines just waiting to explode](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know_14.html) gives me little comfort it will remain consistent.