# What are 'environments' in the language-lawyer tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

The [language-lawyer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-lawyer) description states:

> For questions about the intricacies of formal or authoritative
>   specifications of programming languages ***and environments***.

**What does *environments* refer to?** Programming languages don't have environments. Moreover, formal specifications (particularly seen in C and C++, which is what's the tag most about) are even more disassociated from implementation-dependent details in order to retain abstraction.

I would be tempted to ask what tag should be used then. But it's unclear because I can see at least these interpretations:

- A specific problem found in a certain environment. But, again, languages themselves are not concerned about that. I'd rather consider tagging the accused environment, for example [linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linux) or [windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows);
- Specification of environments. I would consider as such, for example, ABI specification questions: but it somehow goes beyond what the tag name is supposed to indicate — is it *language-lawyer* or *environment-lawyer* (although we don't have one currently)?

Comment: It's a [meta tag that I wish were burninated](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256512/16587); but it probably will never be.

Comment: Runtime environments like JVM and CLI and the standard library implementation included with a C or C++ compiler have a formal specification as well.  I doubt that word will be missed, just propose an edit.